# How to use Serilog.Log.ForContext with F# function or C# Method

Tags: c#, f#, serilog

Using [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) and F# how to use `.ForContext` with functions? it appears it only accepts type classes:

```ml
type A()=
  log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<A>() // ✅
```

```ml
let f _ =
  log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<f>() // compile error
  log = Serilog.Log.ForContext(f.GetType()) // the information is not the same as A where it gives module + type path
```

What would be the right way to add the context of a F# function or a C# method (which I presume should be the same problem)?

---

So far my solution has been using this function which return SourceContext exactly as using a class (`moduleFullName+className`):

```ml
let logFromFn _ =
  Serilog.Log.ForContext
    ("SourceContext",
     StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType
     |> fun dt -> dt.FullName + "+" + dt.Name)
```

1. As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557042/9130688), it might be expensive, I use it in places where it would be called once in the whole program.
2. It works well in F# functions inside modules, not so good in for example, the entry point file, where it returns `program+program`

Comment: Consider using `typeof<T>` operator.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've tried but cannot figure how to use `typeof` in this case.

Comment: Is there a ForContext(Type) overload? It might just be using ToString if there is only an object overload.. if so, x.GetType().GetName() might show a more equivalent result. IIRC Type.ToString() shows the FullName which is not assembly-qualified.

Comment: it does exists, it complains with `Serilog.Log.ForContext(typeof(f))`:

A unique overload for method 'ForContext' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.  Known type of argument: 'a  Candidates: - Serilog.Log.ForContext(enricher: Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher) : Serilog.ILogger - Serilog.Log.ForContext(enrichers: Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher []) : Serilog.ILogger - Serilog.Log.ForContext(source: Type) : Serilog.ILogger
The generic function 'typeof' must be given explicit type argument(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods don't have a `Type` associated with them so you can't use either of the `ForContext<T>()` or `ForContext(Type type)` overloads. Since functions in an F# module are compiled to static methods inside a static class (the module), the same applies to them. As a simple alternative, you could set the `SourceContext` property yourself:

```ml
let propName = Serilog.Core.Constants.SourceContextPropertyName
Log.ForContext(propName, "App.Class.Method")
Log.ForContext(propName, "App.Module.function")
```

If you want to be robust to rename operations, you could do something like the following:

```cs
class Class
{
    public void Method()
    {
        var source = $"{typeof(Class).FullName}.{nameof(Method)}";
        var logger = Log.ForContext(Core.Constants.SourceContextPropertyName, source);
        // ...
    }
}
```

```ml
module Module =
    // It's a bit fiddly to get the module type in F#, but here's one
    // approach (credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706890/7694577).
    type private Marker = interface end
    let private moduleType = typeof<Marker>.DeclaringType

    let loggerFor name =
        let source = sprintf "%s.%s" moduleType.FullName name
        let propName = Serilog.Core.Constants.SourceContextPropertyName
        Log.ForContext(propName, source)
    

    // Requires the `nameof` operator from F# 4.7 preview.
    // The function needs to be recursive since it is referenced when calling `nameof`.
    let rec func () =
        let logger = loggerFor (nameof func)
        // ...
```

I'd add that usually the class/module name is enough context to figure out where a message has originated from, so I would suggest leaving out the method/function name from the source context. This would allow you to use the `ForContext<T>()` or `ForContext(Type type)` overloads, and would therefore simplify things a great deal.

Comment: I tend to refactor a lot, so I was looking for a more "refactor proof approach", I also tried to do something with Quotations but cannot refer to the function inside its body unless is `rec`  (which is not a problem with Classes)

Comment: @CodingEdgar - I've edited to include options that are robust to rename operations.

Answer (score 1):

The key complication in F# is that you cannot use a `module` identifier as a type literal, i.e. while you can say `Log.ForContext<TypeName>()`, you cannot do `Log.ForContext<ModuleName>()`.

The best workaround until the language supports using a module identifier as a `Type` and/or a `typeof(ModuleName)` facility is added is unfortunately [to plonk this ugly boilerplate at the top of your `module` definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706890/11635):

```
type private Marker = interface end
let private moduleType = typeof<Marker>.DeclaringType
let log = Log.ForContext(moduleType)
```

---

The other answer obviously answers the question as posed in full. This one answers a different question as IMO:

*As with C#, including the member/function name in the log context is not appropriate idiomatic use of [structured logging](https://serilog.net/) - the message should make sense independent of you needing to know what function/member it's embedded in*.